# FROM --> IMPORT function & return values

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-import, return-value

I'm using python 3.7

How do you handle multiple "returned" values from an imported function after being called? Is there a way to set the return values to variables?

```
File = 'Func_File'
```

In 'Func_File':

```
def how():
    x = x
    y = y
    z = z
    return x, y z
```

So now I import the function from 'func_file' to the script i'm using it on.

```
From func_file import how
```

When I call how(), how can I show the returned values individually?

Comment: your return statement is not inside of the function definition. If it was a typo, then looking your function shows that it returns a tuple of (x, y, z). What do you mean by "how can I show returned values individually?"

Comment: Whether `how` is imported or defined in the file it is called from makes no difference in how it is called.

Comment: @ScottHunter so I call the function. Everything happens correctly and runs fine without error. How can I set the returned values from the function to variables in the file that im calling it in?

Comment: @muyustan What I mean by "how can I show return values individually" is when I call how() is there a way to set the return values to variables?

Comment: `retval1, retval2, retval3 = how()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a, b, c = how ()
print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
```